# Basic Question about Kodaira Dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Greetings friends,

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective variety with canonical divisor $K$.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\lambda_n$ denote the rational map $X \to \mathbb{P}^M$ induced from $H^0(X, nK)$, and let $d_n = dim(im(\lambda_n))$.  Let $\kappa_1$ be the maximum value $d_n$ attains as $n$ ranges over $\mathbb{N}$, where we say that $\kappa_1=-1$ if $H^0(X,nK)=\emptyset$ for all $n$.

Let $\kappa_2$ be the smallest integer so that the sequence $\frac{dim(H^0(X,nK))}{n^b}$ is bounded, where we make the same convention of $\kappa_2=-1$ for above.

I'd like to understand why $\kappa_1 = \kappa_2$; could someone please provide me with a reference that discusses this, or provide a brief sketch as to the proof?

Thank you,
Robert

Comment: Dear Robert, a reference is Lazarsfeld, *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I*, Corollary 2.1.38. 

Comment: You're welcome. I guess I should post my comment as an answer, to stop the question coming back to the front page...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dear Robert, a reference is Lazarsfeld, *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I*, Corollary 2.1.38. Note that the statement there concerns the Iitaka dimension of any line bundle, not just the canonical bundle.

The basic idea of the proof is as follows: given a line bundle $L$ on $X$, one can find a birational morphism $f: X' \rightarrow X$ such that $X'$ fibres over another variety $Y$ of dimension $\kappa_1(L)$. One then compares the numbers $h^0(X,nL)=h^0(X',f^\ast (nL))$ with the number of sections of powers of some ample line bundles on $Y$, which one can compute with Riemann--Roch, to get the desired estimates.